# Detect reconnect in an IBM MQ client application that uses auto-reconnect

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using IBM MQ Classes for JMS (IBM MQ Version 8.0.0.4) with auto-reconnection configured. According to the docs, reconnection happens implicitly. I would like to issue a simple log statement in the event of reconnection. For that reason, I need to somehow get informed, when that happens.

In the IBM docs on page [Application Recovery](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q018380_.htm) I stumbled over section "Detecting failover" where it says:

> **Reconnection aware:** Register an MQCBT_EVENT_HANDLER event handler with
>   the queue manager. The event handler is posted with MQRC_RECONNECTING
>   when the client starts to try to reconnect to the server, and
>   MQRC_RECONNECTED after a successful reconnection. You can then run a
>   routine to reestablish a predictable state so that the client
>   application is able to continue processing.

Unfortunately, I did not find a code example for Java/JMS that demonstrates how and where to register such an event handler. I don't know if that is even supported in my case. Could anyone provide me to the right direction or even provide a code sample? Thank you very much.

**Question Update from February 5, 2020:**

Added the following code example created by myself, after having received Sashi's initial answer from January 27, 2020.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    Object destination = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;

    try {
        JmsFactoryFactory jmsFactoryFactory = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = jmsFactoryFactory.createConnectionFactory();

        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QM_NAME);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, RECONNECT_TIMEOUT);

        connection = cf.createConnection();
        connection.setExceptionListener(new MQExceptionListener());
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        destination = session.createQueue(QUEUE);
        producer = session.createProducer((Destination)destination);
        connection.start();
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
    }
}

public class MQExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener {
    public void onException(JMSException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        if(e.getLinkedException() != null)
            System.out.println(e.getLinkedException());
    }
}
```

This is what I get in the logs:

```
ERROR [Main.main:57] (main) com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager '<hostname>' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '<hostname>(<port>)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
ERROR [Main.main:61] (main) Inner exceptions:
ERROR [Main.main:65] (main) com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
ERROR [Main.main:65] (main) com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host '<hostname>(<port>)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host '<hostname>/<ip>:<port>' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection refused: connect],3=<hostname>/<ip>:<port>,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]],3=<hostname>(<port>),5=RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket]
ERROR [Main.main:65] (main) com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host '<hostname>/<ip>:<port>' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection refused: connect],3=<hostname>/<ip>:<port>,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]
ERROR [Main.main:65] (main) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

**Question Update from February 11, 2020:**

I've added this additions based on feedback received by Sashi on February 5, 2020.

I have tried to build a minimal application that connects to an IBM MQ instance. Here's the code:

*Application.java*

```
public class Application {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        MQWriter writer = new MQWriter();
        int i = 1;
        while (true) {
            String message = "Hello Testing " + i;
            LOGGER.info("Sending message {} to MQ server...", message);
            writer.write(message);
            i++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*MQConnectionDetails.java*

```
public class MQConnectionDetails {
    public static final String HOST = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
    public static final int PORT = 1414;
    public static final String QM_NAME = "QM1";
    public static final String CHANNEL = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN";
    public static final String QUEUE = "DEV.QUEUE.1";
    public static final int RECONNECT_TIMEOUT = 60; // 1 minute
}
```

*MQWriter.java*

```
public class MQWriter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQWriter.class);

    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session = null;
    private Object destination = null;
    private MessageProducer producer = null;

    public MQWriter() {
        try {
            JmsFactoryFactory jff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            JmsConnectionFactory jcf = jff.createConnectionFactory();
            jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, MQConnectionDetails.HOST);
            jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, MQConnectionDetails.PORT);
            jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, MQConnectionDetails.CHANNEL);
            jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, MQConnectionDetails.QM_NAME);
            jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
            jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, MQConnectionDetails.RECONNECT_TIMEOUT);

            LOGGER.info("Initializing connection to write queue {} on {}:{}...",
                    MQConnectionDetails.QUEUE,
                    MQConnectionDetails.HOST,
                    MQConnectionDetails.PORT);
            connection = jcf.createConnection();
            connection.setExceptionListener(new MQExceptionListener());
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            destination = session.createQueue(MQConnectionDetails.QUEUE);
            producer = session.createProducer((Destination)destination);
            connection.start();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error initializing connection to write queue", ex);
        }
    }

    public void write(String message) {
        try {
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
            producer.send(textMessage);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error sending message to write queue", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

*MQExceptionListener.java*

```
public class MQExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQExceptionListener.class);

    public void onException(JMSException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("=====");
        LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
        if (ex.getLinkedException() != null) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getLinkedException().toString());
        }
        LOGGER.error("=====");
    }
}
```

The test scenario I ran is like this:

1. Make sure, IBM MQ is available on TCP port 1414 (IBM MQ Docker container running on Amazon EC2).
2. Run the application above (Application.java) and make sure it sends messages to the queue.
3. Change firewall config on Amazon EC2 security groups by changing port from 1414 to 1415, which makes IBM MQ unavailable to the client.

This is what I've observed:

- Only after 90 seconds of inactivity, the client started throwing exceptions. I do not understand, because my RECONNECT_TIMEOUT was set to 60 seconds, so 30 seconds off here.
- MQExceptionListener is invoked only once (the first time).
- There are no reason codes 2544(MQRC_RECONNECTING) only 2009(MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN) is present. Why is that?

Here is a summary of the exceptions that got thrown:

*Exceptions on console:*

```
2020-02-11 09:50:16,155 INFO [Application.run:21] (main) Sending message Hello Testing 13 to MQ server...
2020-02-11 09:50:17,285 INFO [Application.run:21] (main) Sending message Hello Testing 14 to MQ server...
2020-02-11 09:50:18,413 INFO [Application.run:21] (main) Sending message Hello Testing 15 to MQ server...
2020-02-11 09:50:19,555 INFO [Application.run:21] (main) Sending message Hello Testing 16 to MQ server...
2020-02-11 09:51:45,966 ERROR [MQExceptionListener.onException:14] (JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-6) =====
2020-02-11 09:51:45,966 ERROR [MQExceptionListener.onException:15] (JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-6) com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
An error has occurred with the IBM MQ JMS connection.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
2020-02-11 09:51:45,966 ERROR [MQExceptionListener.onException:17] (JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-6) com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQ delivered an asynchronous event with completion code '2', and reason '2009'.
2020-02-11 09:51:45,966 ERROR [MQExceptionListener.onException:19] (JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-6) =====
2020-02-11 09:51:45,967 ERROR [MQWriter.write:52] (main) Error sending message to write queue
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2007: Failed to send a message to destination 'DEV.QUEUE.1'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQPUT or MQPUT1; however IBM MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1288)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1245)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.access$800(WMQMessageProducer.java:76)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.sendInternal(WMQMessageProducer.java:906)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$ProducerShadow.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:566)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:1428)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendMessage(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:855)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.synchronousSendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:2055)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1993)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1486)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:293)
    at org.example.MQWriter.write(MQWriter.java:50)
    at org.example.Application.run(Application.java:22)
    at org.example.Application.main(Application.java:13)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn$ReconnectionState.recordFailure(RemoteHconn.java:4931)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.setReconnectionFailureInner(RemoteHconn.java:2650)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteParentHconn.setReconnectionFailure(RemoteParentHconn.java:152)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteReconnectThread.bestHconn(RemoteReconnectThread.java:265)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteReconnectThread.run(RemoteReconnectThread.java:115)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227)
2020-02-11 09:51:46,969 INFO [Application.run:21] (main) Sending message Hello Testing 17 to MQ server...
2020-02-11 09:51:46,972 ERROR [MQWriter.write:52] (main) Error sending message to write queue
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2007: Failed to send a message to destination 'DEV.QUEUE.1'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQPUT or MQPUT1; however IBM MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1288)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1245)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.access$800(WMQMessageProducer.java:76)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.sendInternal(WMQMessageProducer.java:906)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$ProducerShadow.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:566)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:1428)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendMessage(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:855)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.synchronousSendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:2055)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1993)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1486)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:293)
    at org.example.MQWriter.write(MQWriter.java:50)
    at org.example.Application.run(Application.java:22)
    at org.example.Application.main(Application.java:13)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn$ReconnectionState.recordFailure(RemoteHconn.java:4931)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.setReconnectionFailureInner(RemoteHconn.java:2650)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteParentHconn.setReconnectionFailure(RemoteParentHconn.java:152)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteReconnectThread.bestHconn(RemoteReconnectThread.java:265)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteReconnectThread.run(RemoteReconnectThread.java:115)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227)
```

**Question Update from February 12, 2020**

Added this sample and findings based on JoshMc's answer from February 11, 2020. My comments on this sample:

- I am now using the MQ* classes and set reconnect options as suggested.
- Reconnect is still not happening though

*MQWriter2.java*

```
public class MQWriter2 {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQWriter2.class);

    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session = null;
    private Queue destination = null;
    private MessageProducer producer = null;

    public MQWriter2() {
        try {
            MQConnectionFactory factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
            factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            factory.setConnectionNameList("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(1414)");
            factory.setQueueManager(MQConnectionDetails.QM_NAME);
            factory.setChannel(MQConnectionDetails.CHANNEL);
            factory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
            factory.setClientReconnectTimeout(MQConnectionDetails.RECONNECT_TIMEOUT);

            LOGGER.info("Initializing connection to write queue {} on {}:{}...",
                    MQConnectionDetails.QUEUE,
                    MQConnectionDetails.HOST,
                    MQConnectionDetails.PORT);
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            connection.setExceptionListener(new MQExceptionListener());
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            destination = session.createQueue(MQConnectionDetails.QUEUE);
            producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            connection.start();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error initializing connection to write queue", ex);
        }
    }

    public void write(String message) {
        try {
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
            producer.send(textMessage);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error sending message to write queue", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

*Console Output*

```
2020-02-12 08:39:11,628 INFO [MQWriter2.<init>:29] (main) Initializing connection to write queue DEV.QUEUE.1 on 54.161.121.207:1414...
2020-02-12 08:39:14,552 INFO [Application.run:19] (main) Sending message Hello Testing 1 to MQ server...
2020-02-12 08:39:15,710 INFO [Application.run:19] (main) Sending message Hello Testing 2 to MQ server...
2020-02-12 08:39:16,841 INFO [Application.run:19] (main) Sending message Hello Testing 3 to MQ server...
...
2020-02-12 08:39:41,973 INFO [Application.run:19] (main) Sending message Hello Testing 25 to MQ server...
2020-02-12 08:41:27,314 ERROR [MQExceptionListener.onException:14] (JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-10) =====
2020-02-12 08:41:27,314 ERROR [MQExceptionListener.onException:15] (JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-10) com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
An error has occurred with the IBM MQ JMS connection.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
2020-02-12 08:41:27,314 ERROR [MQWriter2.write:49] (main) Error sending message to write queue
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2007: Failed to send a message to destination 'DEV.QUEUE.1'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQPUT or MQPUT1; however IBM MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1288)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1245)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.access$800(WMQMessageProducer.java:76)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.sendInternal(WMQMessageProducer.java:906)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$ProducerShadow.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:566)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:1428)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendMessage(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:855)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.synchronousSendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:2055)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1993)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1486)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:293)
    at org.example.MQWriter2.write(MQWriter2.java:47)
    at org.example.Application.run(Application.java:20)
    at org.example.Application.main(Application.java:11)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn$ReconnectionState.recordFailure(RemoteHconn.java:4931)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.setReconnectionFailureInner(RemoteHconn.java:2650)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteParentHconn.setReconnectionFailure(RemoteParentHconn.java:152)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteReconnectThread.bestHconn(RemoteReconnectThread.java:265)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteReconnectThread.run(RemoteReconnectThread.java:115)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227)
```

Comment: Just read [Using automatic JMS client reconnection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119450_.htm). Looks like you have to use property `WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST` instead of `WMQ_HOST_NAME` and `WMQ_PORT` to make automatic reconnect working.

Comment: Hello @DanielSteinmann Hi Daniel, Thanks for your reply and the time to study my problem. Actually, I've tried that already in my example from February 5. 2020 (although it is not visible in the sample code). But it didn't work...

Comment: @AndréGasser, did you manage to eventually resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem at the moment and already starting to get desperate because it's totally unclear from the documentation how to make it work. I see from netstat that as soon as the server becomes unavailable, the client never reconnects.

Comment: Hello @raiks No, unfortunately not. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AndréGasser, no worries. I added an answer to your question, please take a look and mark it as accepted if you feel it might solve your problem. It approaches the original issue from a different angle, because IBM MQ, honestly, is a mess.

Comment: @raiks Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue as the topic starter. After spending hours sifting information available in the internet, speaking to colleagues and pulling hair in an attempt to make the reconnection work, I gave up and made a decision to work around the problem by emulating that incomprehensible reconnection functionality. I hope it will help other people struggling with IBM MQ. I wrote the class that, basically, does 2 things:

1. Repeatedly tries to connect to IBM MQ with an increasing interval between attempts.
2. After connecting, sets an error handler that is fired by IBM MQ when something happens to the connection (using the same logic for reconnection).

First, here's the class itself:

```
package com.raiks.mqclient;

import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSException;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.raiks.mqclient.IbmMqMessageListener;

/**
 * This class implements the reconnection logic for JMS brokers that don't support it
 * In particular, it does it for IBM MQ with its incomprehensible reconnection algorithm
 * It's expected that each connection manager receives a separate connection factory
 * and a message listener - it's not guaranteed for those to be thread safe
 */
public final class IbmMqJmsConnectionManager {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IbmMqJmsConnectionManager.class);
    private static final int INITIAL_RECONNECTION_DELAY_MS = 6000;
    private static final int MAX_RECONNECTION_DELAY_MS = 60000;
    private static final String QUEUE_PREIX = "queue:///";

    private final String connectorName;
    private final JmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private final String queueName;

    private final IbmMqMessageListener messageListener;

    private final int initialReconnectionDelayMs;
    private final int maxReconnectionDelayMs;

    public IbmMqJmsConnectionManager(
        String connectorName,
        JmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        String queueName,
        IbmMqMessageListener messageListener,
        int initialReconnectionDelayMs,
        int maxReconnectionDelayMs
    ) {
        this.connectorName = connectorName;
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        this.queueName = queueName;
        this.messageListener = messageListener;
        this.initialReconnectionDelayMs = initialReconnectionDelayMs;
        this.maxReconnectionDelayMs = maxReconnectionDelayMs;
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to connect to a JMS broker and makes continuous retries with an increasing interval if fails
     * When the maximum interval is reached, issues an error and keeps on trying
     * Sets the exception listener (a callback) in the created JMSContext which calls this method when the
     * connection with the broker goes down due to network issue or intentional connection termination
     */
    public void connectToBrokerWithRetries() {
        String connectionDetails = formatConnectionDetails();
        LOGGER.info("Attempting to connect to JMS broker '{}'. Connection details = {}", connectorName, connectionDetails);

        JMSContext context = null;
        int sleepingTimeMs = INITIAL_RECONNECTION_DELAY_MS;
        int accumulatedSleepingTimeMs = 0;

        // Try to reconnect until we succeed. IMPORTANT! This is a blocking loop that never ends so it must be run in a separate thread
        while (context == null) {
            try {
                context = connectionFactory.createContext(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                LOGGER.info("Successfully connected to the JMS broker '{}'. Connection details = {}", connectorName, connectionDetails);

                boolean hadUnsuccessfulConnectionAttempts = accumulatedSleepingTimeMs > 0;
                if (hadUnsuccessfulConnectionAttempts) {
                    LOGGER.warn(
                        "Before this successful attempt, I spent {} ms repeatedly trying to connect to '{}'. Please check the broker's health. Connection details = {}",
                        accumulatedSleepingTimeMs, connectorName, connectionDetails
                    );
                }

                Destination destination = context.createQueue(QUEUE_PREIX + queueName);
                JMSConsumer jmsConsumer = context.createConsumer(destination);
                jmsConsumer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
                LOGGER.info("Successfully connected to the queue '{}' at '{}'. Connection details = {}", queueName, connectorName, connectionDetails);

                // Sets a callback that will be invoked when something happens with a connection to a broker
                context.setExceptionListener(
                    jmsException -> {
                        LOGGER.warn("Something bad happened to JMS broker connection to '{}'. I will try to reconnect. Connection details = {}", connectorName, connectionDetails);
                        connectToBrokerWithRetries();
                    }
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.warn(
                    "Failed to create a JMS context for '{}'. I will wait for {} ms and then make a reconnection attempt. Connection details = {}",
                    connectorName, sleepingTimeMs, connectionDetails, e
                );
                context = null;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepingTimeMs);
                    accumulatedSleepingTimeMs += sleepingTimeMs;
                    int doubledSleepingTime = sleepingTimeMs * 2;
                    // We double the sleeping time on each subsequent attempt until we hit the limit
                    // Then we just keep on reconnecting forever using the limit value
                    boolean nextReconnectionDelayWillExceedMaxDelay = doubledSleepingTime >= MAX_RECONNECTION_DELAY_MS;
                    if (nextReconnectionDelayWillExceedMaxDelay) {
                        sleepingTimeMs = MAX_RECONNECTION_DELAY_MS;
                        LOGGER.error(
                            "Repeatedly failed to create a JMS context for {} ms. I will keep on trying every {} ms but please check the broker availability. Connection details = {}",
                            accumulatedSleepingTimeMs, sleepingTimeMs, connectionDetails
                        );
                    } else {
                        sleepingTimeMs = doubledSleepingTime;
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String formatConnectionDetails() {
        String connectionDetails = "[]";
        try {
            connectionDetails = String.format(
                "[ host = %s, port = %d, queueManager = %s, channel = %s, user = %s ]",
                connectionFactory.getStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME),
                connectionFactory.getIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT),
                connectionFactory.getStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER),
                connectionFactory.getStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL),
                connectionFactory.getStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID)
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Failed to get the connection details. This is not critical, but the details will be unavailable");
        }
        return connectionDetails;
    }
}
```

And here's how you use it:

```
LOGGER.info("Starting the initial connection thread");
Thread cftInitialConnectionThread = new Thread(cftConnectionManager::connectToBrokerWithRetries);
cftInitialConnectionThread.start();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set an ExceptionListener on connection object after creating a connection. The onException method of the ExceptionListener gets invoked when reconnection attempts are made. Here is an example:

```
    ExceptionListener exceptionListener = new ExceptionListener(){
        @Override
        public void onException(JMSException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            if(e.getLinkedException() != null)
                System.out.println(e.getLinkedException());
        }
    };
    MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
    connection.setExceptionListener(exceptionListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But for some reason, that exception listener does not get fired. I've made sure that setExceptionListener() is called before start(). I presume it isn't working because I am sending messages synchronously (I've read somewhere that the exception listener is only invoked when messages are sent asynchronously). Side note: IBM documentation is talking about event handlers not exception listeners. Is there a way to register event handlers as mentioned? Thanks for your help.

Comment: ExceptionListener is invoked when there's a connection issue. It isn't related how messages are sent or received.

Comment: Hello Sashi, I have added my current sample code to illustrate. Differences I see is that I am not using MQQueueConnection class. Maybe you can spot one or more issues there? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, so far I understand that my code example uses IBM JMS extensions and your code sample is using IBM MQ JMS extensions. Found that here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032160_.htm

Comment: It looks like the exception is being thrown at the cf.createConnection(); itself, i.e. before exceptionListener is set. Is that right? ExceptionListener will be invoked if an existing connection is broken.

Comment: Now as you mention it, I can confirm that this is in fact the case. So in other words there has to be an existing connection and if that breaks, reconnect will be triggered and thus exception listener will be invoked as well. Ok, will do some testing on this and come back to this question. Anyways, thanks for your help so far! Highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Shashi, I've added an example to my question and a couple of observations. See "Question Update from February 11, 2020". Thanks for having a look. André

Comment: I will try your sample and see how it goes.

Comment: The ReconnectTimeout = 60 means, the MQ JMS client will attempt to reconnect to queue manager for 60 seconds. It will give up reconnection attempts after 60 seconds if reconnection is unsuccessful. It does not mean reconnection will trigger after 60 seconds. The reconnection attempt will start once the client detects a connection issue and this depends HBINT property on the SVRCONN channel your application using. Lower HBINT value, the faster the detection of connection issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check this piece of Code, for me is working with IBM WMQ 9.2.3, using a 3 node IBM WMQ Multi Instance with Pacemaker on CentOS 8.

```
package com.ibm.mq.samples.jms;

import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.JMSProducer;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class JmsPutGet {

    // System exit status value (assume unset value to be 1)
    private static int status = 1;

    // Create variables for the connection to MQ
    private static final String HOST = "192.168.49.140"; // Host name or IP address
    private static final int PORT = 10200; // Listener port for your queue manager
    private static final String CHANNEL = "CHANNEL1"; // Channel name
    private static final String QMGR = "HAQM1"; // Queue manager name
    private static final String APP_USER = ""; // User name that application uses to connect to MQ
    private static final String APP_PASSWORD = ""; // Password that the application uses to connect to MQ
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "SOURCE"; // Queue that the application uses to put and get messages to and from
    private static final int RECONNECT_TIMEOUT = 60; // 1 minute
    private static JMSContext context = null;
    private static  Destination destination = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Variables
        JMSProducer producer = null;
        JMSConsumer consumer = null;        
        LocalDateTime now = null;

        try {
            
            setupResources();

            long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
            TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            
            for(int i=0; i>=0; i++){
                producer = context.createProducer();
                producer.send(destination, message);
                //System.out.println("Sent message:\n " + i + " " + message);
                System.out.println("\nMensaje enviado:\n " + i );
                now = LocalDateTime.now();
                System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
                consumer = context.createConsumer(destination); // autoclosable
                String receivedMessage = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 15000); // in ms or 15 seconds
                //System.out.println("\nReceived message:\n " + i + " " + receivedMessage);
                System.out.println("\nMensaje recibido:\n " + i );
                now = LocalDateTime.now();
                System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            context.close();

            recordSuccess();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            recordFailure(ex);
            System.out.println("DETECTING ERROR... RECONNECTING");
            setupResources();
            
        }

    } // end main()
        
    private static void setupResources() { 

        boolean connected = false; 
        while (!connected) { 
            try { 
                // Create a connection factory
                JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
                JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();             
                
                // Set the properties
                cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
                cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);             
                //cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, "192.168.49.140(10200),192.168.49.131(10200),192.168.49.132(10200)");
                cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
                cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
                cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
                cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
                cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
                cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);
                cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, RECONNECT_TIMEOUT);
                cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
                //cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "*TLS12");                

                // Create JMS objects
                context = cf.createContext();
                destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);
                // no exception? then we connected ok 
                connected = true; 
                System.out.println("CONNECTED");
            } 
            catch (JMSException je) { 
                // sleep and then have another attempt 
                System.out.println("RECONNECTING");
                try {Thread.sleep(30*1000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {} 
            } 
        } 
    }

    private static void recordSuccess() {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        status = 0;
        return;
    }

    private static void recordFailure(Exception ex) {
        if (ex != null) {
            if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
                processJMSException((JMSException) ex);
            } else {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("FAILURE");
        status = -1;
        return;
    }

    private static void processJMSException(JMSException jmsex) {
        System.out.println(jmsex);
        Throwable innerException = jmsex.getLinkedException();
        if (innerException != null) {
            System.out.println("Inner exception(s):");
        }
        while (innerException != null) {
            System.out.println(innerException);
            innerException = innerException.getCause();
        }
        return;
   }
}
```

I have added a link in github for any reference https://github.com/fintecheando/IBMMQSample

Answer (score 0):

A few points here that may clear things up for you.

The following line sets the amount of time that MQ will attempt to reconnect to the queue manager once it notices the connection is lost.

```
jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, MQConnectionDetails.RECONNECT_TIMEOUT);
```

How long it takes the client to notice the connection is broken depends on the type of failure, but in the situation you describe it will be based on the `HBINT` setting of the `SVRCONN` channel on the queue manager.

A Heart Beat is sent every `HBINT` seconds when no other normal traffic is passing over the channel.  The TIMEOUT of the channel is based on the `HBINT`, if the `HBINT` is less than 60 seconds then the TIMEOUT is twice the `HBINT`, if the `HBINT` is 60 seconds or larger, the TIMEOUT is the `HBINT` plus 60 seconds.  The TIMEOUT is based on the last time traffic or a heart beat was sent, not when you changed firewall config, although in this case it appears you were sending a message every seconds so this should have been close.

Based on the logs I'm not sure it is picking up the RECONNECT option as I would expect when the reconnect timeout expired that you would get either of these errors instead of `MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN`:

- `MQRC_RECONNECT_FAILED`
- `MQRC_RECONNECT_TIMED_OUT`

In samples I have, I set it this way, maybe try this instead of the way you are currently setting it:

```
jcf.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
jcf.setClientReconnectTimeout(MQConnectionDetails.RECONNECT_TIMEOUT);
```

Based on what I see I would guess your `HBINT` is set to 45 seconds on the `SVRCONN` channel, and the connection is just timing out with `MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN` at 90 seconds and never attempting to reconnect.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, Thank you for that very detailed explanation. Actually, my HBINT is set to 300 when I check it in the IBM MQ GUI on my SVRCONN. I have added another code sample to my question above and set the reconnect options as suggested by you, but still no luck. I am using MQ client libraries version 9.1.4.0 and the 9.1.4.0 official IBM MQ Docker container to test this (8.x is not available as Docker container).

Comment: Then it doesn't make sense that you see it even detect the error before 360 seconds.   You said you "... on Amazon EC2 security groups by changing port from 1414 to 1415, which makes IBM MQ unavailable to the client.", at that point if you attempted to telnet from you client to port 1414 does it hang or do you receive connection refused?  I would suggest instead issue `kill -STOP` against the pid of `amqrmppa`, thus will cause it to stop responding and stimulate a network outage.   You will need to wait 360 from the last traffic for it to notice.   Set `HBINT(15)` for a quicker 30sec timeout.

Comment: When I switch port in the security group I get the same error as if shutting down the Docker container (which should be the same as killing the process IMHO). This is what I get in both cases: 

`C:\Users\André>telnet <IP> 1414
Connecting To <IP>...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1414: Connect failed`

Comment: Is that a immediate response or a hang then response?

Comment: The `-STOP` will pause the process.   `-CONT` will unpause it.

Comment: Ok I was able to do a `kill -s SIGSTOP` on the `amqrmppa` process. After that the client stopped sending messages. After running a `kill -s SIGCONT` on the same pid, the client started to send messages again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207671/discussion-between-joshmc-and-andre-gasser).